# Deleting lines with regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to delete lines from the file that begin with the same word. I'm pretty much sure that the regex is correct, and I'm pretty sure that it does not work. I thought that perhaps it does not work this way so I tried replacing with a none empty string. Yet it does not work. Any suggestions how to fix this or how to do the same thing other way?

```
string pattern = @"^smth";
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 File.WriteAllText(path, rgx.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path), ""));
```

Comment: It has too be something with your regex then.
Did you try the examples here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a regex for that, I think you just need to read the file in line by line, and check if each line starts with `smth`. To enable writing to the same location, just create a temporary copy of your file, and then delete it.

```
var tmpfile = Path.GetTempPath() + ".mytmpfile.txt";
File.Copy(path, tmpfile, true);
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(tmpfile, true))
    {
         var line = string.Empty;
         while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
         {
             if (!line.Trim().StartsWith("smth"))
                sw.WriteLine(line);
         }
    }
    File.Delete(tmpfile);
}
```

Your regex is not bad but if you need to read the whole file into a variable, and then handle the multiline text with a regex, you need to use *multiline* mode: `string pattern = @"(?m)^smth";`. `(?m)` will force `^` to match the start of a *line*, not the end of the whole string. Or use `RegexOptions.Multiline` flag with `Regex.Replace`.

UPDATE:

Your approach is valid, but the regex should look like `(?m)^\s*smth\b.*(?:\r?\n|\z)`:

```
string pattern = @"(?m)^\s*smth\b.*(?:\r?\n|\z)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
File.WriteAllText(path, rgx.Replace(File.ReadAllText(path), ""));
```

However, if you have large files, I'd rather go with a non-regex solution.

Comment: Why exactly do I need the temporary file ? Can't I just make changes in the original file ? Also, what's up the WriteLine thingy ? I wan't to delete the whole line that starts with the word, not write it.

Comment: @DDavid: You could get rid of the temp file by just reading the file contents into a variable and after making sure the file is release, write to it. I just do not know how big your file is. I usually have to handle > 1GB files :(

Comment: Actually one more question. Could the problem with the regex be that the line starts with whitespaces ? It's a 87KB file :D

Comment: You can remove whitespace with `.Trim()`, and check if the trimmed string starts with `smth`.

Comment: Just checked, and it seems your approach works well, too. I just had to amend the regex a bit so that the whole line that starts with optional whitespace (`\s*`), then the word you want to search for, then any characters up to and including newline or the end of string (`.*(?:\r?\n|\z)`)

Comment: Ended up using your approach instead of regex, there is a line in the file that starts with smths instead of smth and I really need that . Thanks :)        P.S. Although if you know how to keep that but still delete everything starting with smth while using regex I would be really happy :D

Comment: You just need to tell regex engine that you need a whole word `smth` by adding a `\b` right after `smth`. Then, lines with `smths` at the beginning will be kept intact.